# How to update Json file dynamically swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

Hello i need some help here, I'm making an IOS app that gets data from a API and then showing the results on a Table. What I want to do is to update the info in Json file and show result.

ServerData.json file

```
[{
"name": "Steve Jobs",
"children_data": [{
"id": 1,
"name": "Apple"

},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Next Step"
}
]
}, {
"name": "Mark Z",
"children_data": [{
"id": 1,
"name": "Facebook"

},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Insta"

},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Whatsapp"

}
]
}, {
"name": "Bill Gates",
"children_data": [{
"id": 1,
"name": "Microsoft"

}]
}]
```

I just want to update Json file whenever api response changes.How should I do it?

to read file I tried

```
 func loadJson() {

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ServerData", withExtension: "json")!
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! NSArray

        print(json)
        SaveToFile()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

Comment: U need to update values in Table or Json

Comment: This question is to broad as it is written but as mentioned below you can't work with a file in a bundle for this. You need to use a folder in the ordinary file system instead

Comment: @Ben10- update value in Json file

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file is inside your app bundle and the bundle is read-only. so you can not edit that file programmatically.